# Play! framework staging causing NoSuchFieldError when calling routes.Application.index

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

We are using Play 2.1.0. When we launch it using "play run", it works fine. But when we do `play stage; ./target/start -Dconfig.file=/Users/xxxx/Desktop/application.conf`, it cause an error. Below are the trace:

```
! @6enc6p16c - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Application]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:132) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:128) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Application
    at play.libs.F$Promise$6.apply(F.java:401) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.liftedTree2$1(Future.scala:253) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.liftedTree1$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Application
    at views.html.navbar$.apply(navbar.template.scala:40) ~[endovl_2.10-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at views.html.navbar$.render(navbar.template.scala:65) ~[endovl_2.10-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at views.html.main$.mainNavbar$1(main.template.scala:35) ~[endovl_2.10-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at views.html.main$.apply(main.template.scala:43) ~[endovl_2.10-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at views.html.index$.apply(index.template.scala:33) ~[endovl_2.10-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at views.html.index$.render(index.template.scala:64) ~[endovl_2.10-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
^C[info] application - XXXXXX - Application shutdown...
```

Need help...

Below is the line which caused the NoSuchFieldError exception in view.html.navbar.

```
@navItem(routes.Application.index(), "Home")
```

And this is the line of code in navbar.template.scala

```
"""),_display_(Seq[Any](/*11.8*/navItem(routes.Application.index(), "Home"))),format.raw/*11.51*/("""
```

Comment: It pretty-much has to be the configuration file. Either it's not there (is that _really_ the path?) or it's malformed. Remember that [it's a replacement for the original application.conf, not an addition to it](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Configuration)

Comment: it is a replacement(it is complete by itself). I know it's working because it is opening connection to the database. How do I check if it is malformed?

Comment: Aside from selectively commenting-out lines from the .conf file, I don't really know how you could find the source of the issue. The only other thing I could suggest would be to post your `navbar.template.scala.html` file as this seems to be the source of the problem.

Comment: Use `dist` instead  of `stage` and check if problem still appears, that was said that bugfixing cycle of `stage` command is quite slower in comparison to `dist`, so make sure first that's not a fault of the `stage` command itself

Comment: Hi biesior, using dist result in the same problem.